# Issue in locating build binaries from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am a new user for `jenkins`.

I have installed `jenkins` on my local machine and now it is running on `localhost:8080`. Also I have configured a new job (job name is test) and for the source code path I am using my same machine. So i placed my source code under **C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\test**

So my question is, once I build my source using jenkins where those binaries stored. How can I locate those files??

Is it possible to get the binaries of previous build??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise configuring your build to push artifacts to a dedicated binary repository like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/). This is the best way to expose such files to other tools like Maven.

Another alternative to look at s the [Maven Repository plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server) which turns your Jenkins server into a Maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can also archive the binaries at the end of the build, in which case the binaries are associated with the specific build artifacts. The artifacts of a specific build are accessible using a URL (adjusted for your example) similar to:

```
http://jenkinsServer:8080/job/test/NNN/artifact/buildBinary.jar
```

where NNN is the specific build number that generated the binary artifact buildBinary.jar